# pong javaScript move paddle

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have to do a game Pong in HTML 5.
I need to do the javaScript for the paddle (pala) move. 
The paddle for player1 move with the key W and S and the paddle for player 2 with the slide up and down.

I have this

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<header>
<h1>Super Tenis</h1>
</header>
<div id="game">
<div id="marcador">
<span class="puntuacion">Jugador A :
<span id="puntuacionA">0</span></span>
<span class="puntuacion">Jugador B :
<span id="puntuacionB">0</span></span>
</div>
<div id="pista">
<div id="jugadorA" class="pala"></div>
<div id="jugadorB" class="pala"></div>
2
<div id="pelota" style="left: 80px; top: 100px;"></div>
<div id="linea"></div>
<svg width="400" height="100">
<rect width="400" height="100"
style="fill:#81d41a;stroke-width:7;stroke:#ddd"></rect>
</svg>
<svg width="400" height="100">
<rect width="400" height="100"
style="fill:#81d41a;stroke-width:7;stroke:#ddd"></rect>
</svg>
</div>
<div id="espectadores"></div>
</div>
<footer>
Esto es un ejemplo del juego Pong.
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is your JavaScript?
Or are you using some other scripting language to control the paddles?